# Eager loading of activerecord-reputation-system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eager-loading

I have a Post model that is using Twitter's activerecord reputation system to track votes:

Post model:

```
has_reputation :votes, source: :user, aggregated_by: :sum
```

I am attempting to eager load the reputation associate with all posts on an index page.  Following [this](https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system/issues/27), I'm trying to do so with:

```
Post.find_with_reputation(:votes, :all, { :conditions => ["post_id = ?", self.id] })
```

Doing this, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `id' for #<PostsController:0x007f8560c88150>
```

If I simplify to:

```
Post.find_with_reputation(:votes, :all)
```

I get the following error in my view:

```
undefined method `votes' for #<Post:0x007f8560a6b610>
```

Any direction on where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: ... [Eagar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/229044/meagar)?

Comment: Just like your handle ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can use in this way ....

```
@all_videos = Video.includes(:user,:reputations,:tags,:comments).where("videos.user_id !=?",current_or_guest_user.id).paginate(:page =>params[:page], :per_page => 10).find_with_reputation(:views, :all, order: "views desc")
```

includes help out for eager loading using [ActiveRecordRelation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried a slightly modified version of this: <br>
@postsswithrep = Post.includes(:user,:reputations).where("posts.user_id !=?",current_user.id).find_with_reputation(:votes, :all, order: "votes desc")    but unfortunately this still gives me "undefined method votes.." when calling @postwithrep[0].votes

Comment: @dmt2989..try changing to this                                        `has_many :evaluations, class_name: "RSEvaluation", as: :source  
has_reputation :votes, source: {reputation: :votes, of: :self}, aggregated_by: :sum`

Comment: @Milind- unfortunately this still results in "undefined method 'votes'" when I attempt to call post.votes in the view

Comment: @dmt2989...i think you have not configured the activerecord_reputation gem properly..please go through http://railscasts.com/episodes/364-active-record-reputation-system and tell me that you have followed the same.